# How to append big HTML snippets into DOM with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, ejs

I have an app which uses EJS templating to populate data.

In order to add new projects I have made a simple input form which takes all required parameters.

After an input completed an Ajax request being sent, on success I want to inject this snippet into DOM.

In simple words - After new project added I want to display play instantly by injecting into DOM **without reloading the page**

Is there an elegant way of inserting this `div` ladder as a template into DOM? It works,

```
<div class="projects">
    <div class="projectHeader">
          <div class="projectTitle">
            <span>
              <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editDeadLineModal">
                <i data-id="<%=project.id%>" class="projectDeadline far fa-calendar-alt fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Set Deadline"></i>
              </a>
            </span>
            <h5 class="projectName <%=project.id%>" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Deadline <%=deadline%>" style="align-items: center;">
              <%=project.name%>
            </h5>
            <%}%>
          <div class="projectButtons">
            <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit Project Title">
              <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editProjectTitleModal">
          <i id="editProjectName" class="editProject fas fa-pencil-alt" data-name="<%=project.name%>" data-id="<%=project.id%>"></i>
            </a>
            </span>
    
            <i class="separatorDash fas fa-minus"></i>
    
            <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete Project">
              <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteProjectModal">
                <i id="deleteProject>" class="deleteProject far fa-trash-alt" data-id="<%=project.id%>"></i>
              </a>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

What I have tried is recreating the entire div ladder in `string` and append it to parent node.

Like this:

```
    // Add new Project
    $('#addNewProjectBtn').on("click", function() {
    $("#newProjectModal").on('show.bs.modal', function() {
      $(".confirmNewList").on("click", function(event) {
          var url = '/addNewList';
          var newListTitle = $("#newListNameInput").val()
          event.preventDefault();
          $.post({
            url: url,
            data: {
              listName: newListTitle
            },
            success: function(result) {
              $("#newProjectModal").modal('hide')
              $("#newListNameInput").val('');
              var id = result.data.id
              var name = result.data.name
                  
//Append new project 
                  $(".projects").append("<div class='project col-4' id='project" + id + "'> <div class='projectHeader'> <div class='projectTitle'> ...and so on until the end")
                },
                error: function(err) {
                  console.log(err);
                }
              })
            }
          }
        })
       })
  })
```

In simple words - After new project added I want to display play instantly by injecting into DOM **without reloading the page**

Is there an more elegant and specially efficient way of inserting this `div` ladder as a template into DOM?

The method which I have tried above - works, **But** on attempt to interact with it by calling modals - modals do not get it's `data-*`, as well the bootstrap tooltips don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I discovered that the `event handler` can be delegated.

Since the html snippet I am trying to append to `projects` is added after `document.ready` (document is loaded and handlers are bind) the only thing required to make the new snippet be `active` on event is to `delegate` the event handler to the parent of element that is `appended`.

Like this :

```
$("body").delegate("#addNewProjectBtn", "click", function() {
$("#newProjectModal").on('show.bs.modal', function() {
      $(".confirmNewList").on("click", function(event) {
          var url = '/addNewList';
          var newListTitle = $("#newListNameInput").val()
          event.preventDefault();
          $.post({
            url: url,
            data: {
              listName: newListTitle
            },
            success: function(result) {
              $("#newProjectModal").modal('hide')
              $("#newListNameInput").val('');
              var id = result.data.id
              var name = result.data.name
                  
                 //Append new project 

                  $(".projects").append("<div class='project col-4' id='project" + id + "'> <div class='projectHeader'> <div class='projectTitle'> ...and so on until the end")
                },
                error: function(err) {
                  console.log(err);
                }
              })
            }
          }
        })
       })
  })
```

By delegating the event handler to it's parent - the event handler is preserved in the parent.

Answer (score 1):

1. you can try create new html file instead, and append like this in your page

   ```
   $.get("yourfile.html", function (data) {
     $("#appendToThis").append(data);    // or use .html();
   });
   ```
2. OR you can directly pass this HTML structure from your backend, so you can directly use append function.

Comment: thank you for the tip. Nevertheless I have found a solution below